# Solr, Service Unavailable 503

Tags: ubuntu, solr, jetty

I've just install jetty 9 and solr 4.4.0, I tried to access `http://localhost:8080/solr` but got 503 service error "service unavailable" when try to access solr. try to run `sudo service jetty check` I got this result:

```
agan@dancing:/var/www/sites/all$ sudo service jetty start
Starting Jetty: . . . OK Tue Jan 28 09:39:50 UTC 2014
agan@dancing:/var/www/sites/all$ sudo service jetty check
Checking arguments to Jetty:
START_INI      =  /opt/jetty/start.ini
JETTY_HOME     =  /opt/jetty
JETTY_BASE     =  /opt/jetty
JETTY_CONF     =  /opt/jetty/etc/jetty.conf
JETTY_PID      =  /var/run/jetty.pid
JETTY_START    =  /opt/jetty/start.jar
JETTY_LOGS     =  /opt/jetty/logs
CLASSPATH      =
JAVA           =  /usr/bin/java
JAVA_OPTIONS   =  -Dsolr.solr.home=/opt/solr  -Djetty.state=/opt/jetty/jetty.state -Djetty.logs=/opt/jetty/logs -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty -Djetty.base=/opt/jetty -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp
JETTY_ARGS     =  jetty.port=8080 jetty-logging.xml jetty-started.xml
RUN_CMD        =  /usr/bin/java -Dsolr.solr.home=/opt/solr -Djetty.state=/opt/jetty/jetty.state -Djetty.logs=/opt/jetty/logs -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty -Djetty.base=/opt/jetty -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar jetty.port=8080 jetty-logging.xml jetty-started.xml

Jetty running pid=3018
```

how to get it fixed?

regards,

Comment: hava you started the solr service using `java -jar start.jar`, any special parameters used?

Comment: `/solr ---> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2f594d{/solr,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-solr.war-_solr-any-7029770634037556391.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/solr.war}`
I got that message when access `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: Check your solr logs. You probably have some problems in your configuration files that prevent solr to be start normally.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this thread was last active, but I had the same issue and managed to get around it by upping the JVM heap memory used by Solr.

Here's the command which solved it for me: `./solr restart -m 4g`. After restarting, I was able to use and reindex Solr successfully.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029904/how-can-i-set-jvm-memory-in-solr-5-0) a useful thread with alternative options to increase the JVM heap space.