# How can I set JVM-Memory in Solr-5.0

Tags: solr

How can I increase heap space memory in Solr-5.0? I just want to set minimum and maximum Heap space memory of Solr.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This info is in the WIKI: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Taking+Solr+to+Production#TakingSolrtoProduction-MemoryandGCSettings

`SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms10g -Xmx10g"`

Answer (score 30):

How about using -m option

`./solr restart -m 1g`

From `./solr --help` -

> -m  Sets the min (-Xms) and max (-Xmx) heap size for the JVM, such as: -m 4g results in: -Xms4g -Xmx4g; by default, this script sets the heap size to 512m

Comment: @RonakShah Try below on your console.  
  
`./solr --help`  *-*   
  
`-m <memory>   Sets the min (-Xms) and max (-Xmx) heap size for the JVM, such as: -m 4g  results in: -Xms4g -Xmx4g; by default, this script sets the heap size to 512m`  
  
This exactly answers the question.

Comment: @RonakShah This is indeed an answer to the question. It is describing an another way of setting JVM heap space which is what question is about! Please do not criticize a good answer.

Answer (score 10):

Follow the below steps to increase the JVM memory in Solr:

1. Open solr.in.cmd in any text editor (path: bin/solr.in.cmd)
2. Add the **set SOLR_JAVA_MEM=-Xms1g -Xmx1g** ( it will set the minimum and maximum Java heap memory by 1 GB. however you will only able the see 981.38 MB in solr dashboard)
3. save the solr.in.cmd file and restart the solr

Answer (score 3):

For Centos 7 the modification is in the file bin/solr, e.g. to increase it to 5G :

```
vim /opt/solr/bin/solr
```

Edit the block of code:

```
JAVA_MEM_OPTS=()
if [ -z "$SOLR_HEAP" ] && [ -n "$SOLR_JAVA_MEM" ]; then
  JAVA_MEM_OPTS=($SOLR_JAVA_MEM)
else
  SOLR_HEAP="${SOLR_HEAP:-512m}"
  JAVA_MEM_OPTS=("-Xms5g" "-Xmx5g")
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the post... Worked for me with Solr 8.3 on CentOS as well. Methods in other answers above did not.

Comment: Editing a program's defaults is not the way. You'll lose this when you update. Edit the appropriate config files, please. In the case of Solr 7, there's commented out directives you can customise in the default /etc/default/solr.in.sh.