# Reindexing Solr: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space solr

Tags: java, solr

I indexed a directory containing 16k files of pdfs/docs..etc and everything worked great. However, I tried to reindex my collection, and I got the "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space solr" error for every line that Solr tried to index. I looked into the issue online already, and I tried to change my indexing command from `java -Dc=collection -Drecursive -Dauto -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar c:/folder`  to `java -Dc=collection -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Drecursive -Dauto -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar c:/folder` but I got the same errors (I don't know if it was right of me to add those commands though). I've attached an image of my collection storage information. How can I fix this error?

[image]

Comment: Is the error thrown by the `post.jar` file, or is it thrown inside Solr? If it's being thrown inside Solr itself, changing the parameters for `post.jar` won't do anything.

Comment: @MatsLindh it is in the solr logs file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this:

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8849/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-during-solr-index-rebuilding

Start solr with the following arguments to incease its memory:

`solr start -m 4096m`

Comment: I tried your input and it didn't work :( no difference, the errors still all appear.

Comment: with `solr` you can set the memory flag. See my answer edit

Comment: You'll have to edit the `solr.in.sh` file with your parameters if you want this to remain across restarts instead of having to remember it each time you start Solr.

Comment: I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029904/how-can-i-set-jvm-memory-in-solr-5-0 but now using the restart solr command doesn't even work so my memory is not being updated/changed